# Why setter/getter method called before the onMeasure method in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom view in my app.

In my custom view, I have some Setter and Getter methods along with onMeasure() method.

No matter how many times I execute code, why the setter/getter method always execute before onMeasure() of my custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Android encounter a custom view, it follows below sequence to render it.

1. Creation of Custom View : This means "Constructor" defined in Custom view will be invoked in order to initialize custom view's fields.
2. Inflating the Layout form XML: onFinishInflate() : Next, system invokes **onFinishInflate** once view and all of its children has been inflated from XML. This is the last phase of inflation, after all child views have been added.

By this time the custom view is kind of "Live" in a system, and hence it's fields and methods(setter/getter) are accessible.

After call to setContentView(),system **prepares** the view for rendering.

3.Layout related callbacks: After inflation completion, system invokes onMeasure(int, int). In Fact, This method is invoked by measure(int, int).

4.Drawing: This is called when View's content to be rendered. It is onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas).

In the sample code, by the time system is "preparing" custom view for rendering, app is invoking custom view's methods (setter and getter), and hence the output.

**Intresting Point**:
The thing about measurement and layout is that there's no guarantee or requirement that a view be attached to a window when it happens. ListView in particular performs measurement of item views before attaching them, and it's often quite useful to perform this sort of speculative measurement of detached views when calculating things like the ideal size of something.

This above point is discussed on below Link, which has very useful and detailed discussion on kind-of "lifecycle" of custom view.

https://plus.google.com/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN

Comment: thx for you answer,that's very wonderful,helps me know more about view's drawing process

Comment: Sure!! Custom view is in itself is very interesting to explore and sometime poses interesting situations like you mentioned in your Question!!

Comment: @Amy: Your question is still shown as "unanswered" and if you got what you want (means the understanding of why the setter/getter method execute before onMeasure()), then you should mark any one of the 3 Answer as "Accepted", so that this question will be helpful to others visiting SO.

Comment: Ah~Thanks for your reminder,i find my question is different from before??My code lost

Comment: I edited this question(only sentence formatting) Yesterday and I too was surprised that code was removed. I guess your code adds value to post and hence better if you can add that to add more value to post.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much for helping me~I will post the code again few days later~

Answer (score 2):

Because the view hierarchy has not had a measure and lay out pass performed on it yet. Android uses a message queue for UI events. After setContentView, it schedules a measure and layout pass of the view hierarchy. This is not immediate, and since the views exist in memory, you can certainly call methods on them like your sample code does.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class takes care of creating Phone Window ; top level view hierarchy in which you can place your customized UI by calling setcontentview(resourceId).

View gets drawn to window and then gets processed in 2 stages : measure pass and layout pass. Both are top down recursive traversal of your view hierarchy (tree). During measure pass, every view has stored its measurements i.e. dimensions, styles and properties.

The drawing and processing of view to top level Phone Window is done in secondary thread which has been taken care by Surface View which punches whole and adjusted its location in the window. So you cannot rely activity main thread timings with Surface View thread timings.

More significantly, while calling methods you are accessing view using activity main thread which has relatively less heavier operations to perform then Surface View secondary thread and hence the onMeasure call is delayed
.

Comment: I don't think custom views and Android Widgets have any different life cycle. I don't have enough reputation points to explain my point.